# Imprimir div com appendChild

Tags: javascript

Estou tentando imprimir com appendChild, sem que seja necessário montar utilizando document.createElement, sei que é possível mas não sei como, com o innerHTML funciona mas ele apaga tudo, segue abaixo:

```
var div = "<div id='teste'>valorqualquer</div>";
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(div);
```

**//Mas apresenta a mensagem abaixo:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
```

Já tentei isto (mas faz imprimir apenas texto):

```
div =  document.createTextNode(div);  

document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(div);
```

**Olha a estrutura que preciso montar:**

```
<div id="erroDeCampos" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document"> 
        <h3 class="center">Campos com erro:</h3>                  
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <strong>Erro!</strong> You should <a href="#" class="alert-link">read this message</a>.
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Para cada campo que meu formulário apresentar será criado esta estrutura, mas fazer isto acho que ficaria um código muito grande, segue parte do código:

```
var divElement = document.createElement("div");
divElement.setAttribute("id", "erroDeCampos");
divElement.setAttribute("class","modal fade bs-example-modal-sm");
divElement.setAttribute("tabindex", "-1");
divElement.setAttribute("role", "dialog");
divElement.setAttribute("aria-labelledby", "mySmallModalLabel");    

var divElementModalAninhado = document.createElement("div");
divElementModalAninhado.setAttribute("class", "modal-dialog modal-sm");
divElementModalAninhado.setAttribute("role", "document");

var h3ElementAninhado = document.createElement("div");
h3ElementAninhado.setAttribute("class", "center");
h3ElementAninhado.innerHTML = "Campos com erro";

var divaninhadoaoh3acima = document.createElement("div");
```

Comment: O jeito correto é com `document.createElement`. Por que você não quer usar isso?

Comment: porque existe varias elementos um dentro do outro e com valores bem distinto se eu substituir apenas alguns valores e manter a estrutura já sera o suficiente para eu colocar dentro de um for junto com as mudanças que preciso.

Comment: Coloca um exemplo mais preciso da sua situação e explica melhor o que está tentando fazer.

Answer (score 0):

Não dá pra entender bem as suas restrições. Você precisa passar um nó do DOM pro `appendChild`, não adianta passar texto. Isto funciona, não sei se te atende:

```js
var div = document.createElement('div');  
div.id = 'teste';
div.innerHTML = 'valor qualquer <strong>valendo HTML</strong>';
    
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Comment: Como disse não posso utilizar esta estrutura pois não quero criar inúmeros elementos como o createElement

Comment: Eu não entendo sua restrição. Você não precisa substituir o body inteiro, só pontualmente onde quiser. Aliás o papel do appendChild não é substituir nada, é incluir algo.

Answer (score 0):

Para isso você deve utilizar o método `insertAdjacentHTML()`

Exemplo de uso:

```
elemento.insertAdjacentHTML(posição, texto);
```

Posições:

**beforebegin** Antes do elemento.
**afterbegin** Dentro do elemento, antes de seu primeiro filho (childNode).
**beforeend** Dentro do elemento, após seu último filho (childNode).
**afterend** Após o elemento.

Demonstração:

```js
var div = '<div id="teste">valorqualquer</div>';
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', div );
```

```html
Corpo da página!!!
```

> Verifique na documentação a compatibilidade de navegadores.

Link para a documentação

- [insertAdjacentHTML()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)